# "To support", "in support of" and "in support for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, of-for

What should be the best use of "support" to fill the gap in this sentence?...

> The doctor's association has threatened to go on indefinite strike ___________ their teachers
>
> **a. to support/ b. in support of/ c. in support for**

Comment: There's no question here, Sudhir. What are you looking for?

Comment: I am asking best usage of “To support”, “in support of” and “in support for” in this sentence. @StoneyB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **in support of** and **to support** are correct.

> The doctor's association has threatened to go on indefinite strike **to support** their teachers.
>
> The doctor's association has threatened to go on indefinite strike **in support of** their teachers.

Kelly was correct in that *to support* implies direct help--as if the strike will directly cause a change in the doctor's assocation.

*In support of* implies indirect help--the doctor's association is threatening to go on strike  for moral support. The strike itself may not do much, but it's a statement--the doctor's assocation cares about their teachers.

Answer (score 1):

Both "to support" and "in support of" are grammatically correct. "To support" has a slightly stronger connotation of direct help, while "in support of" could suggest moral support or making a statement. That's a very slight and subtle difference though, and a lot of people might not make that distinction.

I don't think "in support for" is idiomatic. It doesn't seem to be used this way. (A Google search shows that "in support for" mostly comes up in phrases like "a drop in support for X," which means the amount of support dropped, not that something was dropped to support X.)

So, either "to support" and "in support of" is fine. If you want to distinguish between direct help and moral support, I suggest "to support" for more direct help and "in support of" for moral support.

Comment: Please help someone

Answer (score 0):

First of all prepositions are a bit tricky in English. In most cases the use of prepositions depend on the context; hence, there are no strict rules governing the use of prepositions. To answer your question, here is my take on it.

**To support** is the infinitive form of the verb *support* and could mean *provide for, help, hold up, back up, back, advocate or promote, etc*. Here are a few examples:

> She struggled *to support* her family. (Means to *provide for*)
>
> Please hold the pillars for a minutes *to support* the roof. (Means to hold up)
>
> The jury asked for evidence *to support* the argument.(Means to back up)
>
> We are here *to support* charitable projects.(Means to help)
>
> Iowans are *to support* Obama. (Means to back)
>
> The main vision of the group is *to support*  human rights.(Means to promote or advocate)

Now according to OED and NOAD, **in support of** is a phrase and means:

> - giving assistance to: *air operations in support of the land forces.*
> - showing approval of: *the paper printed many letters in support of the government.*
> - attempting to promote or obtain: *a strike in support of an 8.5% pay raise.*

**In support for** means roughly the same as *in support of* in your example. Here are a few examples:

> The new survey shows a drop *in support for* the war.
>
> The new survey shows a drop *in support of* the war.

That said, in your example all three are grammatical and mean roughly the same thing. I would use *in support of* not because it's the best fit, but it feels better in the context at issue.

Comment: I don't think your final examples quite work. It's not using "in support for" as a phrase the same way "in support of" is used. Instead "support" is the object of the preposition "in" with a second prepositional phrase, "for the war," modifying "support."